# highcharts is not a function in Ipython

Tags: python, highcharts, jupyter-notebook, ipython

This is the code：

```
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.display import display


statistics_html ="""
<html>
<head>
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline'
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
         """
display(HTML(statistics_html))
```

This is an error message：

```
VM298:3 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:29)
at j (VM160 jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.add [as done] (VM160 jquery.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init.m.fn.ready (VM160 jquery.min.js:2)
at new m.fn.init (VM160 jquery.min.js:2)
at m (VM160 jquery.min.js:2)
at <anonymous>:2:9
at b (jquery.min.js:2)
at Pe (jquery.min.js:2)
at S.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:2)
```

It has no problem without referencing the plug-in. If you display plain text, there will be no errors. Who knows how to modify it so that it doesn't report errors? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try another approach (without jquery) from this article: https://gist.github.com/PhE/5686342

Comment: thank you. It still made the same mistake. Highcharts depends on jQuery.

Comment: `Highcharts depends on jQuery.` that's not true - Highcharts is a JavaScript library, doesn't need to use jQuery. Have you tried the second approach from the link that I shared?

Comment: I tried all the cases you shared, and they all made the same mistake.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thank you. I found it was an environmental problem, but I couldn't solve it. I implemented visualization on other python.